# Promql How to count the number of values for the current day

Tags: grafana, promql

I need to calculate the number of values for the current day (from 0:00 to the current time) using PromQL and display it on Grafana.

I came up with this formula:

sum((count by (category) ((metrics_end_time{system=~"$system", category=~"$category"}) >= (floor(timestamp(metrics_end_time{system=~"$system", category=~"$category"}) / 86400) * 86400))))

I tried similar with hour(), time(), minute, but it doesn`t work

*metrics_end_time returns the end time of the thread in unixtime

But my formula returns sum of metrics in the last 24-36 hours

Comment: Your logic of detecting current day is flowed: `timestamp` of the metric returns moment of metric being scraped up. So `timestamp` for metric an hour ago will be that hour ago +-5min.

Comment: Also, `sum(count by(label) (something)` is equivalent to `count(something)`, IIUC. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

assuming **To** field of your dashboard time range is always is somewhere today you can use something like this:

```
count(
 last_over_time(
  (
   metrics_end_time{system=~"$system", category=~"$category"}
   and on() timestamp(up)>=floor(timestamp(up@end())/86400)*86400
  )[1d:]
 )
)
```

Here:

- `metric and on() timestamp(up)>=floor(timestamp(up@end())/86400)*86400` returns values of metric if they occurred after today's midnight,
- `last_over_time( (..)[1d:] )` stretches results for a day: we cannot count events which occurred in different time, but we can stretch them and count "now".

Notice, theoretically, if you want this to work for other days, you can change time filter to something like `floor(timestamp(up)/86400)==floor(timestamp(up@end())/86400)`, but it becomes cumbersome, and I'm not 100% sure how it will behave.

Comment: i tried your soulution, but it returns wrong value

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

sum(count_values("category", (last_over_time((metrics_end_time{system=~"$system", category=~"$category"} >= floor(timestamp(metrics_end_time{system=~"$system", category=~"$category"}) / 86400) * 86400)[$__range:]))))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).